# Orthogonality on continuous real interval

Tags: definite-integrals, real-numbers, orthogonality

Given $C[-2,2]$ and it's equipped with the inner product $$(f, g):=\int_{-2}^2 f(t)g(t)dt$$
I'm trying to figure out figure out how to determine the real numbers $c$ (if they even exist) for which $3x$ is orthogonal to $x+2c$.

I'm pretty confused on how to do this. My first thought was just to evaluate the integral. So I let $$f(t)=3x$$ $$g(t)=x+2c$$ I multiplied those together to get $$\int_{-2}^2 (3x^2+6xc)dt$$ took the integral and evaluated $$x^3+3cx^2=>[(8+12c)-(-8+12c)]=16$$
I'm not sure what i've done or how to approach from here in order to obtain what I'm looking for.

**Apologies on the typo in calculation**

Comment: $\;8+8=16\;$ , and thus you got the vectors are never orthogonal.

Comment: Apart for the value of the integral that is $16$, you are right, and you have show that the two functions cannot be orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left.\int_{-2}^2(3x^2+6cx)dx=\left(x^3+3cx^2\right)\right|_{-2}^2=(8+8+12c-12c)=16\implies$$

Those vectors are never orthogonal.

Comment: So I approached this correctly. Is there a similar approach to the "if I let $W$ :=$span${x , e$^x$}. Compute the orthogonal projection of $x+1$ on $W$."? @joanpemo

Comment: @user316861 For this you will need, for simplicity, an orthonormal basis of $\;W\;$ , which you can calculate with Gram-Schmidt. If I am not wrong, these are very messy calculations, but can be done...I think.

Comment: many thanks! I'll give this a look